# Рефакторинг кода и исправление багов. PHP

Tags: php

Необходимо провести рефакторинг, исправить баги, указать уязвимиости и  продокументировать в стиле PHPDoc.

Пока вижу, что подключение к базе идет в цикле (что, понятно, неверно) и закрывается соединение с базой перед ретурном. Мне кажется, надо после (не прав?).

```
function load_users_data($user_ids) {
    $user_ids = explode(',', $user_ids);
    foreach ($user_ids as $user_id) {
        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123123", "database");
        $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$user_id");
        while($obj = $sql->fetch_object()){
            $data[$user_id] = $obj->name;
        }
        mysqli_close($db);
    }
    return $data;
}
// Как правило, в $_GET['user_ids'] должна приходить строка
// с номерами пользователей через запятую, например: 1,2,17,48
$data = load_users_data($_GET['user_ids']);
foreach ($data as $user_id=>$name) {
    echo "<a href=\"/show_user.php?id=$user_id\">$name</a>";
}
```

Comment: После "ретурна" ничего не надо. Никогда.

Comment: Да это ж тестовое задание))) SQLInjection, Закрывать коннекшен можно  после цыкла, до return, что будет если прийдет не строка с айдишникам?)

Comment: Тут минут на 20 разговоров о том, что тут не так и почему) Полный комплект, включая xss/csrf(улыбнуло "как правило, ...")

Answer (score 0):

Любой код после `return` Всегда будет проигнорирован.

По факту, вам нужно перестать использовать `mysqli` И глянуть в сторону `PDO` Или других `CRUD` Систем. 
Вам надо изучить `PSR` И начать именновывать что либо в стиле `camelCase`, также обратите внимание на `XSS` И `CSRF`. В остальном, этот код а целом нужно переписать.